# Fixed footer, changing-height header, how to add scroll to the content between them?

Tags: html, css

I need to compose a page which has a header and a footer, and some textual content in between.

The page size is fixed (an iframe) and has a fixed-height footer, but the header's content can change (it's translated thus the number of text lines varies). Both header and footer should never have a scrollbar. If the content between them is long, a scrollbar should be added to the content itself. Whatever I do, I can't get this to work CSS-only. I either have a scroll to the entire page (or the top area, including the header), or the content div's text extends beyond it's borders.

Here's a fiddle to exemplify my problem:
http://goo.gl/u1iTz
(I want a scroll for the green area only)

Oh, and without JavaScript... :)

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If css3 is an option, you could use FLEXBOX

**[FIDDLE1](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/DVAcV/8/)**  and **[FIDDLE2](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/DVAcV/9/)**

> The Flexbox Layout (Flexible Box) module (currently a W3C Candidate
>   Recommandation) aims at providing a more efficient way to lay out,
>   align and distribute space among items in a container, even when their
>   size is unknown and/or dynamic (thus the word "flex"). -- from [**css-tricks**](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

### Markup:

```
<div class="container">
<header>The header text can change so the height can't be fixed. 
        Should never have a scrollbar
</header>
<div class="content">
Lorem ipsums in futurum.
</div>
<footer>
        The footer's height is fixed
</footer>
</div>
```

### (Relevant) CSS:

```
.content
{
    -webkit-flex: 1 1 auto;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    overflow: auto;
    height:0; /* triggers scroll */
    min-height: 0; /* triggers scroll */
}
```

**A few points to mention:**

1) I only apply flex-grow:1 (ie flex: **1** 1 auto) to the scrollable content; the other items can have a fixed or dynamic height.

2) There's a hack(?) that I saw **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14962468/703717)**, that placing height:0 on the container elements triggers a vertical scroll bar. (Here I used both height and min-height because this hack only worked in firefox with min-height)

3) For this to work in Firefox < 22 - you need to enable the flexbox runtime flag like **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16850368/703717)**

4) Support for flexbox is surprisingly good in modern browsers (see **[here](http://caniuse.com/flexbox)**) but you need to add some browser specific css to get this working (see the above fiddle)

Comment: @MrLipman I updated the fiddle to include the code like in your example

Comment: Thanks! Didn't know this feature :) I need to support old browsers so I'll just do it with JavaScript.